# Warning using mstate package : negative diagonal elements

Tags: r, survival-analysis, markov-models

I am using the `mstate` package with some personal data. I have 3 states that can happen subsequently and then the death state that can happen at anytime.

I created the transition matrix and everything as i should, but then when i try to use the `probtrans()` function, i receive the following warning :

```
> pt.ktc <- probtrans(msf.ktc, predt=0, method="greenwood")
Warning messages:
1: In probtrans(msf.ktc, predt = 0, method = "greenwood") :
  Warning! Negative diagonal elements of (I+dA); the estimate may not be meaningful.
```

Whatever if i use the `greenwood` or `aalen` method, it happens.

I know it is better to have a reproducible example but i can't share publicly the data i am using, and i can't reproduce this error with some random public dataset. Maybe one knows what can cause this warning, so i could check. Before this the `msfit()` function worked fine without any error.

Also, beyond this error i still tried if the ELOS() function would work (it is supposed to calculate the Expected Length of Stay for each state transitions), and i get this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In ELOS(pt.ktc) :
  negative transition probabilities present; ELOS may not be well defined
```

And yes i have in the result a negative length of stay, which is not convenient.

If anyone knows what can cause this so i could investigate, i didn't find any clear things on this subject.